# Async/Await refactor approach

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

When we look at the generated IL code we quickly realize that async mechanics is nice but not free.
How to approach the implementation of such a vampiric code ...
Example :

Imagine that the following method (uninteresting i'm ok) is called almost everywhere in an app..

```
private Dictionary<string,string> _cache = new Dictionary<string,string>();
public string FirstWord(string t)
{
  if(!_cache.TryGetValue(t, out var r))
    cache[t] = r = t[0, t.IndexOf(' ')];
  return r;
}
```

In time this method will become more expensive with a path as a parameter (it could have been a URL or other).
It should naturally evolve into async such as:

```
private Dictionary<string,string> _cache = new Dictionary<string,string>();
public async Task<string> FirstWord(string path)
{
  if(!_cache.TryGetValue(path, out var r))
  {
    var t= await Path.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
    cache[path] = r = t[0, t.IndexOf(' ')];
  }
  return r;
}
```

As this method is used everywhere I am tempted to migrate all of my code in async
This transformation will also force me to do these kinds of things to manage overloads:

```
public async Task<string> FirstWord()
  => await FirstWord("Default");
public async Task<string> FirstWord(string path)
```

The overload without parameters will have to implement an async / await logic to just call the other overload (IL add try / catch...) ...

Should this caching be limited by using a GetAwaiter().GetResult() ...?
Do not do async knowing that this approach will require a general transformation can be more expensive?

Your impressions? Your approach?

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: What do you expect to get from making that call async? This *won't* make the call go faster, it will make it run without blocking the calling thread until the result is needed. And `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` will remove that benefit by blocking that thread. You'll end up with code that blocks but is still somewhat slower

Comment: 1) Don't worry too much. More IL instructions != more cost: instructions are cheap, things like allocations on hot paths or algorithms with bad complexity tend to be the things that add cost. Don't worry about micro-optimizations until performance is an issue, then use a profiler to target and measure them. 2) I definitely wouldn't worry in the uncommon case in your cache example. It's also common to cache the `Task` instead of its result. 3) You can write `public Task<string> FirstWord() => FirstWord("Default")` in that case 4) Do not to mix async and sync. DO NOT do it as an optimization.

Comment: The code isn't thread safe either. Multiple threads may call `FirstWord` with the same path, resulting in conflicts. A `Dictionary` isn't thread-safe either, so if multiple threads try to write to it, you'll get an exception. You need a `ConcurrentDictionary` at least

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the code may be thread safe, depending on whether a `SynchronizationContext` is installed on the current thread (it is installed by default in WinForms/WPF applications). If it is installed, then using a normal `Dictionary` is fine. Concurrent access to the `Dictionary` by multiple threads will be impossible.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it's not. `TryGetValue` can easily allow *two* threads to try reading and storing the value. `File.ReadAllTextAsync` doesn't open files with share access, so this can easily lead to access errors

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, I stand corrected. The code is not thread-safe indeed. What I wanted to say is that the code needs to be thread-safe only if there is multithreading involved. And I see no indication that the OP intends to run the code in an environment that lacks a `SynchronizationContext`. So suggesting a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of a normal `Dictionary` probably violates the YAGNI principal. Regarding conflicts related to concurrent `ReadAllTextAsync` calls for the same file, this is certainly a problem, that a `ConcurrentDictionary` cannot solve by itself IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

> This transformation will also force me to do these kinds of things to manage overloads:
>
> `public async Task<string> FirstWord() => await FirstWord("Default");`

No it doesn't, for one thing you can simply use default parameters, and even if not there's no purpose to awaiting a single function like that. The correct code, and the code the compiler generates, is this:

```
public Task<string> FirstWord() => FirstWord("Default");
```

> Should this caching be limited by using a GetAwaiter().GetResult() ...?

Everything you read on the subject should be telling you never to use that pattern, because it will lead to dead-locks very easily. Use proper `await`/`async`.

> Do not do async knowing that this approach will require a general transformation can be more expensive?

More expensive to whom? The whole idea of async programming is that you don't keep threads busy waiting for things they don't calculate, like I/O in your example. The thread that calls that function will be released to process the next request instead of sitting idle until the DMA operation on the file finishes.

> IL add try / catch...

Just so we're clear, because even though it will absolutely not do it for the code you showed for this (with optimizations enabled, of course), `try` in general is essentially free in .Net. It's actually catching an exception that's expensive. Profile your code before jumping to conclusions!

Comment: Beware that default arguments are hardcoded in the caller code.

Answer (score 0):

A task can be awaited more than once. Even after being completed.

A completed task adds very low overload to the operation.

So, you should cache the task.

And, if you want to make it concurrent, use a ConcurrentDictionary:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string,string> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>();
public Task<string> FirstWordAsync(string path)
    => _cache.GetOrAdd(path, () => Path.ReadAllTextAsync(path));
```

This way, any request for a path that is being read will receive a non-completed task and must wait for it to complete.

Comment: I don't see how a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>` can have a `GetOrAdd` method which returns a `Task<string>`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a more detailed version of Paulo Morgado's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62782431/11178549). By caching tasks instead of naked values you can afford to [elide](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) the `async` from the `FirstWordAsync` method, removing any considerations regarding the efficiency of the method's overloads.

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, Task<string>> _cache
    = new Dictionary<string, Task<string>>();

public Task<string> FirstWordAsync(string path)
{
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(path, out var task))
    {
        task = Materialize(async () => // alternative: Task.Run(async...
        {
            string text = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(path).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var index = text.IndexOf(" ");
            return index == -1 ? text : text.Substring(0, index);
        });
        _cache[path] = task;
    }
    return task;
}

public Task<string> FirstWordAsync() => FirstWordAsync("Default");

private static Task<T> Materialize<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory) => taskFactory();
```